# My "detailed" view page isn't working. The web page content is invisible

Tags: regex, django, expression

EDIT: I fixed the views.py with Av4t4r's code but it still shows no content. **When I type something in voodoo.html it actually shows content, but all of the content inside the {% block content %} are not showing. Why is that?**

Hello I am trying to make a simply gallery app where the first view (listview) is a list of all the persons (which are the objects), and when a user clicks on one it proceeds to the next page with a given pk/id key. But when it comes to that page... the content is blank. Here is what I have:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Images.objects.all(), template_name='imgboard/home.html')),
    url(r'^imgboard/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.voodoofunction, name='voodoofunction'),
]
```

views.py (I feel like this is where the problem is):

```
def voodoofunction(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Moreimages, id=id)
    context = { "object_list": instance, } 
    return render(request, "imgboard/voodoo.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    name_person = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    img_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name_person

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Images'


class Moreimages(models.Model):
        key = models.ForeignKey(Images, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        img_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return str(self.key)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "More Images"
```

listview_code.html

```
{% block content %}
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <p><a href="/imgboard/{{object.id}}">{{object.name_person}}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

voodoo.html:

```
{% block content %}
    <h2>{{ object.name_person}}<br></h2>
    <h4><a href="{{object.instagram}}">{{object.instagram}}</a></p></h4>
    <br>
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <p><img src="{{object.img_url}}", width=350, height="360></img>"</p>
    {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your `views.py` you are simply not using an ID/PK. Try something like this 

`instance = get_object_or_404(YourModel, id=id)
context = {
        "object_list": instance,
    }
return render(request, "imgboard/voodoo.html", context)`
`

Comment: please fix your Python indentation..

Comment: I fixed the views.py with your code but it still shows no content. When I type something in voodoo.html  it actually shows content, but all of the content  inside the {% block content %} are not showing. Why is that?

Comment: Fixed my reply. I meant to say not* showing which is corrected now

Comment: So you *are* passing `object_list` when you return your response in the view? If not, this is your problem; if so, please show your updated code.

Comment: I added indentation and I just updated my first post with updated views.py
It still giving blank content idk what it is. But its everything inside the {% block content %} tags because everything outside of it is showing. But I need the block content stuff for my child templates..

And what do you mean elethan?

Answer (score 0):

Your context has no "object" in it. And your "object_list" is an instance, not a list (so your for loop is doing nothing).